# Kill exec if the parent process terminates

Tags: go

I have a piece of go code like:

```golang
func Foo() {
    cmd := exec.Command("command that takes a long time")
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }


    return
}

func main() {
    Foo()

    panic("program quit abruptly")
}
```

The sleep command will still be active even though the main process ended, is it possible to link these so the `cmd` will be killed if the parent is?

Comment: @CeriseLimón, Sleep was only an example to demonstrate the problem. Pretend like its a command that actually takes a long time (goes forever), and doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desire is that the process you initiated is killed when your program exits, then you can inject a context:

```
func Foo(ctx context.Context) {
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "command that takes a long time")
    _ = cmd.Start()

    return
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    Foo(ctx)
    defer cancel()

    panic("program quit abruptly")
}
```

This code works by creating a context with a cancel function. This context is then sent to `Foo` and from there to the command function. When `cancel` is called, the context will be cancelled, causing the child process to be killed. To ensure that the context is cancelled, we defer the call to `cancel`, which ensures that the context is cancelled when the program exits for any reason, including a panic.

If your desire is to cancel only on panic, you can modify `main` slightly:

```
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    Foo(ctx)
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            cancel()
        }
    }()

    panic("program quit abruptly")
}
```